# how to use navigate in react with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern

I am making a login foam on react using react-redux, kindly suggest to me how I will use navigate here

```
const { isAuthenticated, error, loading} = useSelector(state =>state.auth);
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(isAuthenticated){
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
    if(error){
      // alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  },
  // [dispatch,alert,isAuthenticated,error,navigate]
  [dispatch,isAuthenticated,error,navigate]
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import `useNavigate` at the top of the file like this?

`import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";`

Then, to use it, assign it to a variable:

`let navigate = useNavigate();`

then use it like you have in the code:
`navigate("/dashboard");`